# Typescript: Invalid 'new' expression

Tags: typescript, ampersand

In an attempt to help [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25227309/725866) out I was stubbing out the typescript definitions for the [Ampersand.js](http://ampersandjs.com/) library.  Given the following typescript code, why does the compiler output an *Invalid 'new' experession* error?

**[[Here's a link to run the code using the typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=declare%20module%20ampersand%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20AmpersandState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20todo...%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20AmpersandCollection%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20todo...%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20ModelExtendOptions%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parse%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parent%3F%3A%20AmpersandState%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20collection%3F%3A%20AmpersandCollection%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20ModelSaveOptions%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20patch%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20class%20AmpersandModel%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(attrs%3A%20T%2C%20options%3F%3A%20ModelExtendOptions)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20save%3A%20(attrs%3F%3A%20T%2C%20options%3F%3A%20ModelSaveOptions)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20todo%3A%20%20fetch%2C%20destroy%2C%20sync%2C%20etc...%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20ExtendOptions%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20props%3F%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20session%3F%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20derived%3F%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20AmpersandModelStatic%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extend%3A%20%3CT%3E(options%3A%20ExtendOptions)%20%3D%3E%20AmpersandModel%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0A%0Adeclare%20var%20AmpersandModel%3A%20ampersand.AmpersandModelStatic%3B%0A%0A%0Ainterface%20PersonProps%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20lastName%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20Person%20%3D%20AmpersandModel.extend%3CPersonProps%3E(%7B%20props%3A%20%7B%20firstName%3A%20'string'%2C%20lastName%3A%20'string'%20%7D%20%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20me%20%3D%20new%20Person(%7B%20firstName%3A%20'Phil'%2C%20lastName%3A%20'Roberts'%20%7D)%3B).]**

```
declare module ampersand {
    interface AmpersandState {
        // todo...
    }

    interface AmpersandCollection {
        // todo...
    }

    interface ModelExtendOptions {
        parse?: boolean;
        parent?: AmpersandState;
        collection?: AmpersandCollection;
    }

    interface ModelSaveOptions {
        patch?: boolean;
    }

    class AmpersandModel<T> {
        constructor(attrs: T, options?: ModelExtendOptions);
        save: (attrs?: T, options?: ModelSaveOptions) => void;
        // todo:  fetch, destroy, sync, etc...
    }

    interface ExtendOptions {
        props?: {};
        session?: {};
        derived?: {};
    }   

    interface AmpersandModelStatic {
        extend: <T>(options: ExtendOptions) => AmpersandModel<T>;
    }
} 

declare var AmpersandModel: ampersand.AmpersandModelStatic;


interface PersonProps {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

var Person = AmpersandModel.extend<PersonProps>({ props: { firstName: 'string', lastName: 'string' } });

var me = new Person({ firstName: 'Phil', lastName: 'Roberts' });
```

> Invalid 'new' expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My extend method was returning an instance of AmpersandModel, not the ApersandModel's constructor function.  Corrected code:

```
declare module ampersand {
    interface AmpersandState {
        // todo...
    }

    interface AmpersandCollection {
        // todo...
    }

    interface ModelExtendOptions {
        parse?: boolean;
        parent?: AmpersandState;
        collection?: AmpersandCollection;
    }

    interface ModelSaveOptions {
        patch?: boolean;
    }

    interface AmpersandModel<T> {
        save: (attrs?: T, options?: ModelSaveOptions) => void;
        // todo:  fetch, destroy, sync, etc...
    }

    interface AmpersandModelConstructor<T> {
        new (attrs: T, options?: ModelExtendOptions): AmpersandModel<T>;
    }   

    interface ExtendOptions {
        props?: {};
        session?: {};
        derived?: {};
    }   

    interface AmpersandModelStatic {
        extend: <T>(options: ExtendOptions) => AmpersandModelConstructor<T>;
    }
} 

declare var AmpersandModel: ampersand.AmpersandModelStatic;

interface PersonProps {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

interface IPerson extends PersonProps, ampersand.AmpersandModel<PersonProps>{}

var Person = AmpersandModel.extend<PersonProps>({ props: { firstName: 'string', lastName: 'string' } });

var me = new Person({ firstName: 'Jeremy', lastName: 'Danyow' });
```